# Raycast не из камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу свою игру, в которой мне необходимо узнавать сведения о соседнем объекте, я хочу для этого использовать raycast hit, но мне необходимо отправлять его из заданной точки, а не камеры. Как можно реализовать это, или есть какие-то способы получше?

Единственное, что мне удалось найти, это:

```
RaycastHit hit;
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
```

Comment: Что такое соседний объект? Который расположен рядом? С какой стороны рядом? В чем проблема указать для луча [Ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Ray.html) origin - начало луча? Почему в решении, которое предлагаете вы, вы используете Input.mousePosition, а в вопросе нет нчиего про надобность использования позиции мыши?

Comment: Я и пишу, поскольку кроме данных двух строчек я не смог ничего найти, и прошу показать, как можно реализовать Raycast не из Camera.main, а другой точки, записанной в виде Vector3, или другим способом. И спасибо за подсказку с Ray origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ray](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Ray.html) (луч) имеет такие параметры, как

- [direction](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Ray-direction.html) -
  [нормализованный](https://habr.com/ru/post/131931/) вектор направления вектора
- [origin](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Ray-origin.html) - начальная точка луча, откуда он запустится.

Для того, чтобы запустить вектор из определенной точки нужно просто указать эту в качестве параметра origin.

> А тот код, который приведен у вас в примере, во-первых, неполный, во-вторых, запускает луч из позиции мыши "перпендикулярно" экрану

Comment: Спасибо, я нашел недостающий код и наконец-то разобрался.